# Linker error while trying to use COM object created in with IDL

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, com, idl

I want to use a COM object in my VS2012 project. For these purposes I was given an IDL file that describes the object. I have used MIDL to generate a header file which looks (partly) like this:

```
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_COComponent;

#ifdef __cplusplus

class DECLSPEC_UUID("bla bla bla")
COComponent;
#endif
```

However, when I include this header into my project, and try to use `CLSID_COComponent` in a `CoCreateInstance` call:.

```
CComPtr<IModelService> m_IModelService;

hRes = m_IModelService.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_COComponent, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL);
```

I get an linker error:

```
Error   123 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_COComponent
```

However if I use `__uuidof(COComponent)`, it works fine. Also when removing the `EXTERN_C` from the generated code, it compiles.

The exact same code has been used in a different project, where I have seen it work. My question is, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: MIDL normally also generates a .c file that contains the GUID definition, /iid command line option.  Seems you didn't include it in your project.  Using the __uuid keyword is indeed the simple and entirely valid workaround.

Comment: [The Interface UUID File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367283.aspx). Usually has the format *<ComObject>_i.c*. Needs to be compiled and linked into the final executable image.

Comment: Great, that did the trick indeed! If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The exact same code has been used in a different project, where I have seen it work. My question is, what could I be doing wrong?

That means, there's nothing wrong with the code itself. It has to be something external to the code. The hint is in the `CLSID` declaration:

```
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_COComponent;
```

`EXTERN_C` expands to `extern "C"`, so the full statement is telling the compiler that there is a symbol called `CLSID_COComponent` of type `const CLSID`, but it is defined someplace else. Don't try to look it up, have the linker stitch the pieces together later on.<sup>1</sup>

The definition for the `CLSID` is also generated by MIDL. It's placed in an [Interface UUID File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367283.aspx). The default name for this file is *<idl base name>_i.c* (can be overridden with the [/iid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367329.aspx) MIDL switch). You have to include that file into your project, so that the linker will find the symbol.

Alternatively, you can use the [__uuidof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaah6a61.aspx) operator, that doesn't need the Interface UUID File. I cannot tell you, which compiler magic makes this works. But if Hans Passant calls it a [*"valid workaround"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772767/linker-error-while-trying-to-use-com-object-created-in-with-idl#comment66840710_39772767), I'm not going to question that.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Removing the `EXTERN_C` allows this to compile, by **defining** the symbol. It will fail at runtime, though, since the `CLSID` doesn't store the correct value.*